# How to create a method for adding Binary Number in java without using if, else statement

Tags: java, methods, binary, addition

I am making this because this a task given to us by our professor, and I am having some difficulties because we are not allowed to use any if else statement or even conversion.

I already tried some method but the expected outcome would not appear.

```
public static int addBinary (int num1, int num2)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int carry= 1;
    int a;
    int b;


x= num1 + num2;
    y= x - 2;
    a= (carry) + (y);

    return a;

}
```

The outcome must show the sum of 1 and 1 is 10 but the output I got is "The sum of 1 and 1 is 1"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I'm confused by the stated prompt - if you are given two int numbers, whatever function you implement to convert them to something else will be a "conversion". `Integer.toBinaryString(num1+num2);` is the simplest implementation of this.

Comment: We are now allowed to use conversion by using type cast, but we are not allowed to put it inside the main yet we must put it below the main and make a method then to use our method all we need to do is to have a function call from the the method to main

here's my method but still error Can I ask what is wrong?

public static int addBinary (int num1, int num2)
 {
  int x;
  int y;
  int a;
  int b;
  
  x=Integer.valueOf(num1,2);
  y=Integer.valueOf(num2,2);
  a= x + y;
  b= Intger.toBinaryString(num1+num2);
  
  return b;
 }
}